# Circuit Starving Question

Tags: voltage, current, filter, dc-motor

I have a circuit where 2 DC motors are connected to 4 AA batteries and being controlled by an Arduino microcontroller.

Whenever the motors start, they starve other components in the circuit and it is enough to reset the Arduino (since it is essentially quickly being turned off and on). What can I do to help smooth out the current? Adding a capacitor on the power output didn't seem to help.

Comment: motor details required and activation circuit.

Comment: If PWM control of the motors then you might try starting them more slowly.  otherwise a separate supply, or isolate a big cap for the arduino with a resistor or diode. (As per stro32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem here is that the sag of the 6V supply (i.e. 4X AA batteries) does not need to be very much to cause total havoc with the VIN to +5V regulator in the Arduino.

For example if you are using the Arduino Uno there is an MC33269D-5.0 LDO regulator on the board to regulate the VIN down to the +5V required for the board operation. This LDO is specified as needing a headroom of 1.25V @ 500mA (1.35V @ 800 mA) above the output voltage to ensure proper operation. The typical value in the data sheet says that you can expect the regulator to work with 1.0V of headroom.

So this means that when you are operating the Arduino with a 6V input (with nice fresh batteries) it takes very little sag in the battery voltage to drive the LDO into undefined and not working territory. As a matter of fact the operation with 4x AA cells is nominally on the hairy edge even with out the additional load of the motor. Then think what happens when the battery starts to go lower as it gets used. You literally fall off the cliff.

You should consider at least a 6.5V supply from some other type of source or start to look at using 5X AA cells.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the circuit functions much better with an extra battery. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My point of view: measure the time of the power wave, add a Schottky diode，then add a capacitor to be keep the power when the motors start. Capacitance of the capacitor depends on the wave time.

Answer (score 1):

Could you power your arduino from a separate battery from the 6V pack you are using for your motors? Then the arduino could control the motors via a relay or a transistor, and your arduino power supply would not be affected by the voltage sag on the motor circuit.

Is the 6V power supply connected to Vin on the arduino? If so, you might be running the arduino at substantially less than 5V, since the 5V regulator needs about 2.5V of headroom.

Comment: It seems like an ugly solution to the problem... I want to run the whole circuit from one power source, and there must be a way to do it properly.